# Bash script creates terminal that persists for further work

Tags: bash, gnome, gnome-terminal

Some similar posts did not clear up this question:

How do I create a terminal from inside a bash script,
giving initial commands (e.g. `df`,   `pwd` etc) and
allowing me to keep working on it after the script ended?

Normally the terminal is killed after an optional command
(`gnome-terminal -x ...`).

```
gnome-terminal  --working-directory="$HOME/Documents"
```

is not working for some reason.

Specifically I want to mount a partition via script and work on
its files afterwards.

I use Ubu 20.04, Gnome 3.36.8.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME/Documents -- sh -c "df ; pwd ; bash"
```

may do what you want. For me, the option `--working-directory` works as expected, but if it does not for you, you can include a `cd` command after `sh -c`.

Comment: Maybe useful to add the warnings about `-x` and `e`: `# Option “-x” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.`, since OP mentions it.